# How to set :hover and :active color on a react jsx component?

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic, tailwind-css

```
<button 
   onClick={fetchExchangeRates}
   style={{ backgroundColor: `${selectedColor}` }}
   className="hover text-white px-3 py-1 flex justify-center items-center gap-2 text- rounded-md"
   > Convert
   <FontAwesomeIcon className='text-white' icon={faArrowRight} />
</button>
```

I have a redux store set up from there I will fetch the color and apply dynamically. I can apply the main color . But I can't apply ux improvement features like button click and hover effect.

Challenge here is we need to do that dynamically.

One more problem I noticed is :

```
  const colorOptions = ["#C53030", "#2F855A", "#1E40AF", "#6B46C1", "#D97706", "#B83280",];
  const colors = [
    { hover: "#dc2626", main: "#b91c1c", active: "#991b1b" }, // red
    { hover: "#16a34a", main: "#15803d", active: "#166534" }, // green
    { hover: "#2563eb", main: "#1d4ed8", active: "#1e40af" }, // blue
    { hover: "#9333ea", main: "#7e22ce", active: "#6b21a8" }, // purple
    { hover: "#ea580c", main: "#c2410c", active: "#9a3412" }, // orange
    { hover: "#e11d48", main: "#be123c", active: "#9f1239" }, // rose
  ]
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5 sm:gap-2 rounded-md bg-white p-5 sm:p-2 w-max mx-auto">
      {colors.map((color, index) => {
        const c = "blue";
        const backgroundColor = `bg-[blue]`; // works fine with string values
        // const backgroundColor = `bg-[blue]`; // Works fine as template literal
        // const backgroundColor = `bg-[${c}]`; // but doesn't work if we try to modify the string
        console.log(backgroundColor);
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            // style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
            className={`h-12 w-12 sm:h-6 sm:w-6 rounded-full ${backgroundColor}`}
            onClick={() => handleColorChange(color)}
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </div>

  )
```

So what I learned is we can't dynamically change the tailwind class values. we can write predefined values like `bg-[#fff]` and it will work. But here comes another problem I am not only going to use the color on the background only but also on text and borders. so I need to write something like this :

```
colors = [
   {backgroundHover: "bg-red-600", backgroundColor : "bg-red-700", backgroundAction : "bg-red-800", textColor : "text-red-700", borderColor : "border-red-700"},
{backgroundHover: "bg-green-600", backgroundColor : "bg-green-700", backgroundAction : "bg-green-800", textColor : "text-green-700", borderColor : "border-green-700"},
{backgroundHover: "bg-blue-600", backgroundColor : "bg-blue-700", backgroundAction : "bg-blue-800", textColor : "text-blue-700", borderColor : "border-blue-700"},
{backgroundHover: "bg-orange-600", backgroundColor : "bg-orange-700", backgroundAction : "bg-orange-800", textColor : "text-orange-700", borderColor : "border-orange-700"},
]
```

which is bit like hardcoded and not so programmatic .

**So my expectations** :

1. I want to change the **hover** and **active** colors on a button dynamically and add also set the color of text and border dynamically.
2. Its possible in the hard way using Tailwindcss but how do we do it with normal CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider setting CSS variables on the element. This would allow you to use dynamic colors with Tailwind variants:

```
{colors.map((color, index) => {
  <div
    …
    style={{
      '--main': color.main,
      '--hover': color.hover,
      '--active': color.active,
    }}
    className="… bg-[--main] hover:bg-[--hover] active:bg-[--active]`}
  >
```

You could then extend this to text and border colors too like:

```
text-[color:--main] border-[color:--main]
```

---

I am using the CSS variable shortcut syntax introduced in Tailwind `v3.3`. If you are using a Tailwind version 3 lower than this, you would need to add the `var()` function like `bg-[var(--main)]`.

Comment: I am using latest Tailwind 3.3.3 

I have fixed it. I made use of onMouseEnter. onMouseLeave, onMouseDown, onMouseup event listeners to achieve the results. 

It was a very strange problem to be honest. I don't know some simple and basic javascript that's all. 

Here is the code : https://github.com/bishalkar10/Currency-Globe/blob/main/src/components/Theme.jsx